# Dynamic routing to template directory in JSF2

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets

I'm trying to build a WebApp with JSF2. One of my goals is to make use of templates located in different directories:

```
template1/
    template.xhtml
    index.xhtml

template2/
    template.xhtml
    index.xhtml
```

My plan is to make a managed bean that holds information about which template that currently is in use, then another managed bean takes care of the navigation sending the user to the right template path. (The user is going to the url http://webapp.com/index.xhtml, but actually http://webapp.com/template1/index.xhtml is served)

My question is how do I do this dynamically from the start? Should I make use of a filter, or maybe a servlet?

Any help would very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, look for a filter.

Comment: Ok, thanks, do you know of some sample-code or something similar that could get me started with this?